# C# and Entity Framework : stop adding duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class

```
public class SetParts
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Part part { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Part being

```
public class Part
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string part_num  { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and Color being

```
public class Color
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string rgb { get; set; }
}
```

I get a list from an API of 'SetParts' but different can contain the same 'Color' as another 'SetPart' (same applies to 'Part').

The issue I'm having is each time I add 'SetParts', it's duplicating Color.... and Parts

How can I easily stop this?

EDIT:
Each SetParts retrieved is unique, but they can contain the same color and parts
The Part and Color are identical in this circumstance, (same id's)

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    db.AddRange(data); 
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

data is a List retrieved via API

Comment: Show us the code that is causing the duplication, please;

Comment: when you get the colours from the API - what `id`s do they have? also: please share more information about your db-setup, and how you're actually adding stuff. without showing your code, we can not debug your code.......

Comment: In addition to fixing your code to not create dups, you need to fix your model to prevent them.  Every one of those should have a unique index to prevent duplicates. EG `Part.Part_Num`, `Color.Name`.

Comment: Please spend some time reading [the C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions). PropertyNamesShouldUsePascalCase, classes should not have plural names

Answer (score 0):

> How can I easily stop this?

Retrieve an existing color from the DB or use the ID of an existing color and set that (for classes that map by having a ColorID property at the child end)

Right now you're probably just letting the API supply a SetParts with a Blue color, and saving it, and then another SetParts with another Blue color and saving that too..

They won't be duplicates (they'll have different IDs), but they'll probably all be Blue.. DB's only doing what you tell it to; if you want to use an existing color (e.g. the Blue with id=1), assign that existing color before you save